# How to fix a key fob Toyota 4runner 2017?

Tags: toyota, key, fob, 4runner

I accidentally washed my key fob in the washer. My toyota has a push start button. We have use a hair dryer on it. Still won't work

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try taking it apart and drying it, then put a new battery in it.

Comment: does it work if you hold it to the button?
Likely its beyond repair unfortunately but holding it to the button may still work.

Comment: The best way to dry electronics is using dessicant or in a pinch, dried rice, however that takes days to work and it's unlikely to resurrect your fob.

Comment: [Is this what your fob looks like?](https://dealerinspire-image-library-prod.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/ZTe9Ap2NsUzd4yDQloAgCWEN9cQB2lSEkxqLVov0.png)

Comment: My husband called someone. We are going to get it towed there and they are going to give us a new key. Thank you for the feed back